# Многопоточная обработка файлов в Qt C ++

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность

Как организовать многопоточную обработку файлов (открытие, сбор данных, закрытие) из массива QFileInfoList?

Я нашел пример кода, где вы можете просто поместить его в 1 отдельный поток. И если например файлов будет 20 и более, и вам нужно разделить их, например, на 4 потока.

```
dir.cd(pathFolder);
dir.setFilter(QDir::Files | QDir::Hidden | QDir::NoSymLinks);
QStringList nameFilter;
nameFilter << "*.txt";
QFileInfoList list = dir.entryInfoList(nameFilter);
```

Это то, что происходит при обработке. Он просто читает 1 строку, проверяет совпадение и добавляет ее в QTableWidget.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
    QFileInfo fileInfo = list.at(i);
    QFile file(fileInfo.filePath());
    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        QTextStream in(&file);
        QString line = in.readLine();
        if(line.indexOf("str")!=-1)
        {
            ui->listWidget_ps->addItem(fileInfo.fileName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Так же как любую другую многопоточную обработку. Используйте потоки или встроенный в Qt thread pool: `QRunnable` и компанию.

Comment: Попробуйте QtConcurrent::run

Comment: Добавлю, что вызывать функции интерфейса из не основного потока нельзя, так что надо будет использовать сигналы для связи потоков-воркеров с основным

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый быстрый способ сделать то, что вы хотите, без существенного изменения кода - воспользоваться openmp. Для этого проделываем следующие шаги:

1. "Включаем" openmp, для этого добавляем в .pro файл следующее:

   ```
   QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -fopenmp
   LIBS += -fopenmp
   ```

   после этого может понадобиться очистить проект и вручную дернуть `qmake`
2. Объявляем сигнал для доставки найденных имен файлов из рабочих потоков в основной:

   ```
   signals:
       void sendFileName(QString fileName);
   ```
3. Заменяем в цикле добавление строки в `QListWidget` на emit этого сигнала:

   ```
      if(line.indexOf("str")!=-1)
          emit sendFileName(fileInfo.fileName());
   ```
4. Соединяем сигнал с методом добавления строки в лист (я делал это в конструкторе окна тестовой программы, но по сути надо сделать это один раз где-то перед испусканием сигнала)

   ```
   connect(this, &MainWindow::sendFileName, ui->listWidget_ps, QOverload<const QString &>::of(&QListWidget::addItem));
   ```

   Обратите внимание на конструкцию `QOverload`, `addItem` не является слотом, из-за этого "старый" синтаксис соединения не сработает. Также `addItem` имеет перегрузки, в которые не умеет "обычный новый" синтаксис, чтобы подружить его с перегруженными методами, используется `QOverload`.
5. Командуем openmp выполнить наш цикл в многопоточном режиме:

   ```
   #pragma omp parallel for
       for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
       ...
   ```

По моим тестам прирост производительности примерно в 4.5 раза на массиве данных в 1000 файлов.